# Update XML element in Oracle using join to other tables

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a XML stored in a XMLTYPE column that has encrypted elements, which I need to replace with the decrypted value by joining to other tables.

```
-- Sample XML
<Root_Element xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2019/01/notification">    
    <DocID>ABCD1234</DocID>
    <InsertDate>2019-03-01</InsertDate>
    <TimeSeries>
        <Received_DocID>123456</Received_DocID>
        <Encrypted_ProviderID>PROV001</Encrypted_ProviderID>
        <Point>
            <Encrypted_BidID>BD001</Encrypted_BidID>
            <Amount>1.63</Amount>
        </Point>
    </TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>
        <Received_DocID>123456</Received_DocID>
        <Encrypted_ProviderID>PROV001</Encrypted_ProviderID>
        <Point>
            <Encrypted_BidID>BD002</Encrypted_BidID>
            <Amount>1.63</Amount>
        </Point>
    </TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>
        <Received_DocID>987654</Received_DocID>
        <Encrypted_ProviderID>PROV002</Encrypted_ProviderID>
        <Point>
            <Encrypted_BidID>BD101</Encrypted_BidID>
            <Amount>1.85</Amount>
        </Point>
    </TimeSeries>
</Root_Element>

-- PROVIDERS table

ProviderID Encrypted_ProviderID
PROVEU     PROV001
PROVUK     PROV002

-- BIDS table

Received_DocID BidID Encrypted_BidID
123456         1111  BD001
123456         2222  BD002
987654         3333  BD101


-- Expected output
<Root_Element xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2019/01/notification">    
    <DocID>ABCD1234</DocID>
    <InsertDate>2019-03-01</InsertDate>
    <TimeSeries>
        <Received_DocID>123456</Received_DocID>
        <Encrypted_ProviderID>PROVEU</Encrypted_ProviderID>
        <Point>
            <Encrypted_BidID>111</Encrypted_BidID>
            <Amount>1.63</Amount>
        </Point>
    </TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>
        <Received_DocID>123456</Received_DocID>
        <Encrypted_ProviderID>PROVEU</Encrypted_ProviderID>
        <Point>
            <Encrypted_BidID>2222</Encrypted_BidID>
            <Amount>1.63</Amount>
        </Point>
    </TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>
        <Received_DocID>987654</Received_DocID>
        <Encrypted_ProviderID>PROVUK</Encrypted_ProviderID>
        <Point>
            <Encrypted_BidID>3333</Encrypted_BidID>
            <Amount>1.85</Amount>
        </Point>
    </TimeSeries>
</Root_Element>
```

The  tag will be repeated around 1000 times within the XML, so the update needs to be quick and if possible in one statement.

Is there an easy and quick of doing this using XMLQuery?

The database is Oracle 11.2.0.3

Comment: XML only allows one root tag.  When you combine files you will get an array at root level.  You could add a new root to file like this : <new_root><Root_Element></Root_Element><Root_Element></Root_Element><Root_Element></Root_Element><Root_Element></Root_Element></new_root>  So all you have to do is create new file with <new_root>  Then append the 1000 files and then terminate with </new_root>

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't make the question clear. There is only one XML and I need to update the encrypted elements within it and generate a new XML file. The values to be decrypted are held within Oracle tables, so somehow I need to join the XML with the Oracle tables using Xquery.